# Oozie 4.1.0 build error with Hadoop 2.x

Tags: hadoop, build, oozie

Trying to get the Oozie 4.1.0 build with Hadoop 2.x specifically 2.4.1 or 2.5.1. Based on this link gauravkohli.com/2014/08/26/apache-oozie-installation-on-hadoop-2-4-1/ , I have edited the pom files. The build m/c have restricted connectivity and maven artifacts are sourced from internal Repos.

Here is maven build output.

[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Main .................................. SUCCESS [  1.023 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ................................ SUCCESS [ 13.186 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.1.1.oozie-4.1.0 .............. SUCCESS [  0.600 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 1.1.1.oozie-4.1.0 ....... SUCCESS [  0.054 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.1.1.oozie-4.1.0 Test ......... SUCCESS [  0.120 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Utils 1.1.1.oozie-4.1.0 ........ SUCCESS [  0.560 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.3.0.oozie-4.1.0 .............. SUCCESS [  2.940 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.3.0.oozie-4.1.0 Test ......... SUCCESS [  0.209 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 2.3.0.oozie-4.1.0 ....... SUCCESS [  0.067 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Utils 2.3.0.oozie-4.1.0 ........ SUCCESS [  0.693 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 0.23.5.oozie-4.1.0 ............. SUCCESS [  2.062 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 0.23.5.oozie-4.1.0 Test ........ SUCCESS [  0.145 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 0.23.5.oozie-4.1.0 ...... SUCCESS [  0.047 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Utils 0.23.5.oozie-4.1.0 ....... SUCCESS [  0.690 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs ........................... SUCCESS [  2.423 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase 0.94.2.oozie-4.1.0 .............. SUCCESS [  0.160 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase Libs ............................ SUCCESS [  0.427 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog 0.13.1.oozie-4.1.0 ........... SUCCESS [  0.490 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog Libs ......................... SUCCESS [  1.113 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ....................... FAILURE [03:59 min]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog .................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Core .................................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs .................................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ......................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ........................ SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ....................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming ................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ...................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ................................ SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples .............................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ................................ SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie ZooKeeper Security Tests .............. SKIPPED

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 04:29 min

[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-03T20:20:48+00:00

[INFO] Final Memory: 64M/285M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-sharelib-oozie: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-oozie:jar:4.1.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.4.1.oozie-4.1.0, org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-test:jar:2.4.1.oozie-4.1.0, org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-utils:jar:2.4.1.oozie-4.1.0: Could not find artifact org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.4.1.oozie-4.1.0 in internal (http://internalXXXXXXXXX.com/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn  -rf :oozie-sharelib-oozie

ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed

Maven fails to resolve following artifacts 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.4.1.oozie-4.1.0, org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-test:jar:2.4.1.oozie-4.1.0, org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-utils:jar:2.4.1.oozie-4.1.0: Could not find artifact org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.4.1.oozie-4.1.0 in internal (http://internalXXXXXXXXX.com/content/groups/public)

Searched web for exact same artifacts, but none found so far.

Please suggest alternate artifact which can be used or required changes in Oozie pom files for Hadoop 2.5.1.

The Above build log is an side attempt to replicate at least the suggest Hadoop 2.4.1 related changes and build Oozie. Appreciate your inputs to resolve this deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

the same issue was resolved in mine environment by updating the nameserver of the Node, by adding the same in "/etc/resolv.conf".

As per my understanding the Maven access HTTP to build the Oozie Package, so you can update the "/etc/resolv.conf" with the Server IP which is having full HTTP access after words try Building the Package, check if the same got resolved or not.

Comment: Thanks Debjit, I am now trying to build outside these VMs where maven can have unrestricted connectivity. Getting a internet access is time consuming process.